# Fluent validation when model contains property with array of objects

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a model like this

```cs
class Model1
{
    // other properties
    
    public IEnumerable<Model2> Models { get; set; }
    
    // other properties
}

class Model2
{
    // other properties
    
    public IEnumerable<Model3> Models { get; set; } 

    // other properties
}

class Model3
{
    public string[] Values { get; set; }    
}
```

And I want to validate values from model3 to make sure there are no empty strings.

How can I do that with fluent validation?

I've tried this code but I can't validate each value from the Values property.

```cs
public class Model1Validator : AbstractValidator<Model1>
{
    public Model1Validator()
    {
        RuleForEach(x => x.Models)
            .ChildRules(x =>
            {
                // at this point I am unable to use x.ChildRules again
                x.RuleFor(z => z.Models)
                    .NotEmpty(); // validates the array is not empty
            })
    }
```

Comment: See https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html#collections-of-complex-types => `RuleForEach(x => x.Models).SetValidator(new Model2Validator());` and in `Model2Validator` you can do whatever a Validator can do, including setting a rule for "No empty strings".